# How to block everything on Windows 10's firewall and slowly allow the things that I only need?

Tags: windows-10, firewall, windows-firewall, network-traffic, traffic-filtering

I've had just about enough with all the spying and resource usage behind my back on my Windows machine, so I've decided to consider the plausibility of first blocking all network traffic and then slowly allowing the things that I use every day, like Chrome, a few games, and applications, etc.

How plausible is this? I'm pretty much a complete newbie at this stuff, so I don't know if I'd need to like, for example, allow a dozen things just for one application to work or something of the sort. I want to keep the parts of my computer that I don't use or want to disturb under carbonite, mostly for archival purposes and also to save resources.

So, an example scenario would be like this:

1. I block all network traffic on my firewall
2. Then I open Chrome and see on my firewall that something like 'Chrome.exe wants to use the WiFi'
3. Then I allow 'Chrome.exe' to use the WiFi
4. Then I open Minecraft and see on my firewall that 'Minecraft.exe' and 'MinecraftResources.com' wants to use the WiFI
5. Then I allow both things to use the WiFi

How do I make it so that when an application or service wants to use the internet, then the application or service shows up on some list in my firewall application?  I want to explictly allow or disallow the application or service and see what file is causing the thing to be requested

Answer (score 0):

Windows Firewall already does half of this – it blocks all *inbound* traffic (programs listening for connections), just not outbound.

To change this, open `wf.msc`, then open "Windows Defender Firewall Properties", and under your current profile's tab (Public or Private) change the "Outbound connections" setting to "block".

Now all outbound traffic that'll be allowed is what's described in the main wf.msc window's "Outbound Rules" section, just like it was already the case with inbound traffic. (You can use the sidebar to "Filter by Profile" and hide rules irrelevant to your current network profile.)

You can start by disabling all of the enabled outbound rules, **except the Core Networking ones.** (Out of the Core Networking rules, *only* Teredo and Group Policy can be safely disabled, but not the ICMP or IGMP rules – don't waste your or others' time trying to block outbound ICMP error packets.)

Comment: Oh, gosh. I don't think I've ever used Window Firewall ever. It seems like I already have lots of rules in my 'Outbound rules' tab. How do I disable all of them except for the Core Networking ones?

Edit: So I figured out right clicking opens a dropdown menu that lets me simply 'Disable' a rule. I'm still too scared to touch them though. Will 'disabling' all of them except for the ones that say 'Core Networking' in the front cause pretty much every application and service on my computer to think I am offline? ie. No more automatic Microsoft Edge updates, Chrome will think I am offline, etc.